# Saving GIF File via Python's urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Note that I am using the following version of Python:

> (venv) C:\Users\NBenton\PycharmProjects\RES3D_BETA>python Python 3.6.5
>   (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>   on win32

I have tried using the following two scripts to download a single GIF file via a URL.

1)

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urlretrieve('http://www.iframeapps.dcnr.state.pa.us/topogeo/PaGWIS_search/DisplayReportImage.aspx?id=IM209132',
            "C:/Users/NBenton/PycharmProjects/RES3D_BETA/image1.gif")
```

2)

```
from urllib import request

request.urlretrieve("http://www.iframeapps.dcnr.state.pa.us/topogeo/PaGWIS_search/DisplayReportImage.aspx?id=IM209132",
                    "image2.gif")
```

For each of these scripts, the process finishing with exit code 0 - so nothing catastrophic occurred as I far I can tell.

However, both output files (image1.gif and image2.gif) appear as so when viewing each:

[image: Output]

Can anyone offer some insight on this problem? Indeed similar (almost identical) cases are on stackoverflow but not like this.

Comment: It might have to do with the `gif` format itself. Try to associate the file format (`gif`) with Photo Viewer.

Comment: what you have downloaded is the html, you must obtain the url of the image: `http://www.iframeapps.dcnr.state.pa.us/topogeo/PaGWIS_search/WellReports/200001-210000/IM209132.gif`

Comment: @eyllanesc that worked! How/where did you retrieve the info "...200001-210000..."? Also, why does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL being retrieved isn't the image source but an HTML document containing the image.

When you run (or open the URL in the browser):

```
curl http://www.iframeapps.dcnr.state.pa.us/topogeo/PaGWIS_search/DisplayReportImage.aspx?id=IM209132
```

You can view the image `src` in the source document of the document.

```
<!--...-->
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img id="imgPhoto" src="./WellReports/<maskedpath>/IM209132.gif" width="100%" border="0" />
</div>
```

The `src` for the image shows that its location is relative to the URL path i.e.

```
http://www.iframeapps.dcnr.state.pa.us/topogeo/PaGWIS_search/WellReports/<maskedpath>/IM209132.gif
```